# Unable to access github repo anymore: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, ssh

I created a new github.com repository yesterday using the github.com documentation:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

All worked fine and I made a number of commits to the repo, using my Macbook.

Today, I get the above error when continuing to work in my repo and trying to commit new changes.

I ran the following command:

`ssh -Tv git@github.com`

And the output was:

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-ea310e90
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-ea310e90
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:JOrvD5iNbRdhl0EDir7miV/KuRcpzTaEYzH/CJmxNpE
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:JOrvD5iNbRdhl0EDir7miV/KuRcpzTaEYzH/CJmxNpE
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

From reading up on this, i understand the -1 at the end of lines

```
debug1: identity file /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
```

indicates a missing ssh key file. My ssh key is called eastonit_wordpress and is in the ~/.ssh/ directory.

I also noticed that the line:

```
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
```

so i checked this file and it doesn't exist, however on the next line it does state:

```
debug1: Found key in /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/known_hosts:11
```

so that seems good. However, following that line i see this:

```
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:JOrvD5iNbRdhl0EDir7miV/KuRcpzTaEYzH/CJmxNpE
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_xmss
```

so none of these are my key.

Why is it not using my key? How do i get it to use my key?

These other keys are used for work bitbucket repos, but this github.com key id for my own personal project.

The only other file i have updated using github.com documentation is the ~/.ssh/config file which contains the following:

```
Host *
UseKeychain yes

Host *.github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/eastonit_wordpress
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeyChain
```

Any ideas please? Many thanks :)

Comment: Use `ssh-add -l` to show the keys currently present in whatever agent `ssh-add` can reach. Note that you can run more than one agent; each one will only have whatever keys it has, so it's usually not wise to run multiple agents (there's no easy way to tell them apart! they're all named Bruce, er, Agent).

Comment: This is the one key your `ssh -Tv` did actually offer: `debug1: Offering public key: /Users/jameseaston/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:JOrvD5iNbRdhl0EDir7miV/KuRcpzTaEYzH/CJmxNpE` - and it did not work. Presumably your ssh offered that key because both the public and private key files were available locally and/or because the agent had that key loaded.

Comment: Thanks @torek for your response.
When i run ```ssh -Tv``` i get the following returned:
```The agent has no identities.```
I'm not that clever with ssh keys so what steps do i need to take in order to ensure the agent is running each time?

Comment: Ok, I have resolved this issue it seems:

I re-read: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

It states:

"Add your SSH private key to the ssh-agent. If you created your key with a different name, or if you are adding an existing key that has a different name, replace id_ed25519 in the command with the name of your private key file."

I ran ```ssh-add ~/.ssh/eastonit_wordpress``` and it is now working.

I also relaunched vscode and it continues to work.

Many thanks @torek for your help!

Comment: On macOS, there's nothing you have to do to start the (i.e., one single) agent that you want to have running: the OS does that for you when you log in. You do, however, have to use `ssh-add` to *add* your keys *to* the agent if they're not already *in* the agent. There are some tricks to let the agent autoload them but I don't use those myself (because I use other systems, not just macOS, and I don't want to get into bad habits).

Comment: On other OSes, you may need to set up some login-time magic to start the (one, single) agent that you want to have running; the details tend to be OS-specific. Fortunately this is the sort of thing that you can then hide away in some login script and not worry about it after that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
Host *.github.com
...

ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

Your config file entry for github matches "*.github.com", but you're trying to connect to "github.com". "github.com" doesn't match "*.github.com", so ssh doesn't apply the directives in the file.

Change your .ssh/config file to this:

```
Host github.com *.github.com      <-- Note added "github.com"
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/eastonit_wordpress
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeyChain
```

This will cause ssh to apply the section when you connect to "github.com".